# High available stellar core

Tags: stellar-core

I'm looking for a way to run a high available stellar validator core. Right now I run one stellar connected to Postgres DB in a k8s pod.

My question is if I want to for example run 3 nodes do I need to have 3 DBs, one per node?

Is it possible to increase the replication of one node to three and connect all of them to 1 database?

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that it's possible: two or more instances writing to the same storage would likely corrupt some data at some point or at least it would be a huge mess for software updates especially with db schema upgrades. But even if it is possible, with only one database as a single point of failure you would be totally missing the point of high availability.